# Bash command time output to .txt

Tags: bash, unix, stdout, ubuntu-18.04, stderr

Hello I have a bash script that I made intending to measure the time elapsed, CPU% and Memory usage of the script `download_test.sh` with the output being put into a .txt file with the desired output like :

```
Elapsed time: 1263.75s
Memory usage: 62916 KB
CPU usage: 0%
```

The script that executes this looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'RESULTS' >> log.txt
{ /usr/bin/time -f 'Elapsed time: %es\nMemory usage: %M KB\nCPU usage: %P' bash download_test.sh  1 ; }  2>> log.txt
```

However the download terminal progress is also being directed to the .txt file i.e.

```
RESULTS

Downloading:  95%|#########5| 827M/870M [00:00<?, ?B/s]
Downloading:  95%|#########5| 828M/870M [00:00<00:11, 3.68MB/s]
...
Elapsed time: 14.67s
Memory usage: 62592 KB
CPU usage: 0%
```

I am new to using stderr and stdout so have I misunderstood them and how would I resolve this issue?

Comment: Something in `download.sh` does writes those "Downloading" lines to stderr. You need to suppress the output of whatever does it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is `stderr`. You can use below command to print required rows.

`awk '/Elapsed/,/CPU/'`

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'RESULTS' >> log.txt
{ /usr/bin/time -f 'Elapsed time: %es\nMemory usage: %M KB\nCPU usage: %P' bash download_test.sh  1 ; } | awk '/Elapsed/,/CPU/' 2>> log.txt
```